# How to register Autofac type when constructor param has a disposable object

Tags: autofac

I am newbie in Autofac. I am not sure if I am coming up with a right question,

here is how my code look like

```
using (var crmConnection = new CrmConnection(appConfig))
{
    IOrganizationProxy serviceProxy = crmConnection.GetConnection();
    IMyClass _aclass = new MyClass(serviceProxy);
}
```

My question is how do I register type for MyClass with Autofac

Comment: The question is how you're going to register the rest of stuff which you definitely need to do. And that in turn depends on how all this code is going to be used which is totally missing in your question. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AlexanderLeonov I do think my question was on point. My usage of the object is also listed ` IMyClass _aclass = new MyClass(serviceProxy);`. My question was where I said how do I register MyClass. what i did not mention was, I did not want to create the object inside the using and do not want use new key word. I would have thought that is understandable - but that's just me. Again none of links you mentioned said a question needs to be include possible usage as well.

Comment: The links say that question should contain all necessary parts to understand the question. What I mentioned is absolutely necessary to get what you're asking. No one will be guessing missing code. Also, mentioning some additional code in the comments is not going to help. Everything should be in question text. If you think that this code is enough then you'll have to wait for someone else, I'm out.

Comment: @AlexanderLeonov again i fail to see the additional code. I can see the code but just not the additional bit as the line is already there in my question. It is a forum hence I am sure someone else should be able to help or may be ask something that is conceivable.

Comment: If you're asking about DI container then you need to provide the following: relevant code of container setup; all relevant component registrations; code for the classes being registered - at least constructors, not just couple lines - and other parts of the class if they involve, let's say, using of factories outside of constructor; code that resolves components if components are not resolved through parameter injection into constructor. Any missing part easily leads to a completely wrong advice.